# NFS different permissions to subdirectories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I have the following /etc/exports config for my NFS server.

```
/root/share *(rw,fsid=0,no_root_squash)
/root/share/music anne(rw,no_root_squash) alex(rw,no_root_squash)
/root/share/video anne(rw,no_root_squash) alex(ro,no_root_squash)
```

I want anne to have rw access to both directories. I want alex to have only ro access to /root/share/video. The problem with my current config is that they both have rw access.

If I change the first line to

```
/root/share *(ro,fsid=0,no_root_squash)
```

It overwrites every other line and makes all directories read-only.

How can I make the first line take effect only on /root/share ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *very* confused about what constitutes an exported filesystem. `/etc/exports` does not contain an Access Control List - not really. It contains a list of *independent* filesystems and how they should be exported.

Each entry is completely separate from each other and the export name matching is exact, not recursive - if `alex` mounts `/root/share` only the first entry will be used. In the same vein, `alex` cannot mount `/root/share/misc` directly because it is not an exported directory.